# C# - Basic hangman game lives issue

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I'll make it short: Basic hangman game, it loops through player 2 letter choice and if it doesn't match the first character of player 1's word, it'll remove a life, the the second, until it either finds a match or just removed however many lives the player 1 word length is.

I obviously don't want that, I want it to check the array - if none match then remove a life.

```
for (int i = 0; i < playerTwoGuesses.Length; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1400);
            Console.Write("Guess: ");
            count = 0;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    playerTwoGuesses[i] = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    validGuess = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a single character only.");
                }
            } while (validGuess == false);


            for (int j = 0; j < playerOneDisguised.Length; j++)
            {
                if (playerOneCharacters[j] == playerTwoGuesses[i])
                {
                    playerOneDisguised[j] = playerTwoGuesses[i];

                }
                else
                {
                    lives = lives - 1;

                }
            }


            if (lives == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Oh no! It seems you've lost. Closing game in 5 seconds.");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }


            Console.WriteLine(playerOneDisguised);


            for (int k = 0; k < playerOneDisguised.Length; k++)
            {
                if (playerOneDisguised[k] != '*')
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                    if (count == playerOneDisguised.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations you've won!");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Closing game in 5 seconds.");
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So you maybe want to check if the entered letter **is contained** in the word. If not, a life is removed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        bool match = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < playerOneDisguised.Length; j++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < playerTwoGuesses.Length; y++)
            {
                if (playerOneCharacters[j] == playerTwoGuesses[y])
                {
                    playerOneDisguised[j] = playerTwoGuesses[y];
                    match = true;
                }
            }

        }
        if (match == false) {

            lives = lives - 1;
        }
        // Reset it back to false
        match = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping over the array yourself, you can just ask if the guessed char is present in it. You then only need an if statement to handle a guess

```
 if (Array.Exists(playerTwoGuesses, element => element == lastGuess) {
```

Comment: I may've misread something, but why wouldn't `playerTwoGuesses.Contains(lastGuess)` work?

Comment: You're right, that would work fine. It's a better answer, being more readable